# Will updating OS X Server over VNC kill my VNC connection?

Tags: macos, server.app, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I have a Mac Mini sitting in a remote location (another country).  To administer it, I use the screen sharing application.

There is an update for Server, which I would like to install.  However, when I click install, it warns:

> Updating will stop any Server services that are running. Relaunch Server after the update completes to re-enable services.

The issue with that is that VNC is one of the services that Server is providing. My concern is that if Server stops, will I lose my VNC connection, and then be unable to relaunch Server?

How can I "safely" update Server using remote access tools?

(The "it's in a different country" aspect precludes me from being adventurous and just trying it out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VNC is one of the base OS X services, and is not provided by Server.app. You can safely update Server if VNC is the only service you need to connect. I have updated server many times in the past over VNC.

However, if you are using Server's VPN to make a secure connection and are running VNC on top of that, you may have problems. VPN **is** one of the services provided by Server.app, and it will be turned off when updating Server.